# Timeout using SPsite object and U2U Caml query

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, spweb, spsite, time-out

We have 2 collection. 1 is test and other is production environment.
In test collection, I'm writing console application which is using SPSite and SPWeb objects. But it takes nearly 40minutes to get this objects. We are dealing with this problem for a week. Before this, we didnt have any problem, we got this objects instantly. Also U2U Caml query gives timeout error. 
*We tried to system with web browser and it works perfect.
In the other hand, production is still continue without problems. We didn't find any solutions why we get timeout errors.

Comment: so - to sum up the question since some users found it a little unclear: you are basically asking for some directions/suggestion for finding the cause of a performance degradation in programmatic access to SPSite/SpWeb objects that hit your test environment (probably after a still unknown change), right? Are you sure you don't have access to any info about recent changes to the system?

Comment: Things like added site collections, changes in the site structure, changes in the database server etc..